# How to create dynamic business listings in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have created some business listings in wordpress using html and css. Now I want to make it dynamic. How can I do it? There has any business listings plugin in wordpress which I could customize and use it? Or there has any specific code to make it dynamic? Thank you.

To see the design, please visit this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211935016/images/non_Surgical.png

Comment: just code it! it will work, if not Matt Gemmell will help you :  http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Custom post type for Surgical and a separate one for Non-Surgical with custom taxonomies for your categories.

*Resources:*

Creating custom post types: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Creating custom taxonomies: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

**Solution 2:**

Create one custom post type, and one custom taxonomy and split them with categories and sub-categories.

E.g.
Category 1: Surgical
Sub-category: Surgical sub-category

Category 2: Non-Surgical
Sub-category: Non-surgical sub-category.